# extracting text with xpath with different nodes

Tags: xpath, rapidminer

I'm currently trying to extract some text from a website with xPath and Rapidminer. 
I want to extract the "270€" from the following code:

```
<dd class="grid-item three-fifths"> 
<span class="is1-operator">+</span> 
270 € 
</dd>
```

I tried the following which didn't work.

```
//h:dd[@class='grid-item three-fifths']//text()
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Xpath returns 3 text nodes:

1. `""`
2. `"+"`
3. `"270€"`

Try below XPath to fetch only `"270€"`

```
//h:dd[@class='grid-item three-fifths']/text()[string-length() > 0]
```

Comment: Hey Andersson, thanks for your response.

I tried the code you suggested, however it still only returns question marks

Comment: Did you try this solution? Or you've found your own?

Comment: Hey Andersson, I tried what you suggested and it sill returned a question mark. So far, I didn't manage to solve the problem

Comment: I don't see question mark in provided HTML sample. Can you share exact HTML?

Comment: true, there is no question mark in the html, thats why I wonder why it doesn't work out.
the exact code is: 
<dd class="is24qa-nebenkosten grid-item three-fifths"> <span class="is24-operator">+</span> 270 € </dd>
from the following website: https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/99020787?referrer=RESULT_LIST_LISTING&navigationServiceUrl=%2FSuche%2Fcontroller%2FexposeNavigation%2Fnavigate.go%3FsearchUrl%3D%2FSuche%2FS-T%2FWohnung-Miete%26exposeId%3D99020787&navigationHasPrev=false&navigationHasNext=true&navigationBarType=RESULT_LIST&searchId=d3565480-7ffe-38fc-b60c-9aa3dc88914b#/

Comment: class name of `dd` is incomplete in sample provided initially. Try this one `//dd[@class='is24qa-nebenkosten grid-item three-fifths']/text()[string-length() > 0]`

Comment: yep I corrected that already but it doesn't work. I shortened it in the initial post just to keep it simple.
Rapidminer still returns question marks

Comment: I guess this is Rapidminer issue as XPath is correct and Firepath returns desired output with this XPath

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous post string-length filter can be used but `[string-length() > 0]` still brings 3 nodes. Both 'enter' and '+' text contents have a character.

`[string-length() > 1]` should work.

If you are sure about item position (in this case it is 3rd position)

```
//dd[@class='grid-item three-fifths']//text()[3]
```

If you are sure it is always last item:

```
//dd[@class='grid-item three-fifths']/text()[last()]
```

You can get text node after span in dd:

```
//dd[@class='grid-item three-fifths']//span/following-sibling::text()
```

Look for euro sign:

```
//dd/text()[contains(.,'€')]
```